# Can I replace some values at once with dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Now I have to do like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', '-']})
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('A', 'cat').replace('B', 'rabit').replace('C', 'octpath').replace('D', 'spider').replace('E', 'mammoth').replace('F', 'snake').replace('G', 'starfish')
```

But I think this is long and unreadable.
Do you know a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a dict of your replacement values and call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) on the column passing in your dict, to handle values that are not present you can pass param `na_action='ignore'`, this will return `NaN` or `None` as you want to keep your existing values if not present you can call [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna) and pass your orig column:

```
In[60]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', '-']})
d = {'A':'cat','B':'rabit', 'C':'octpath','D':'spider','E':'mammoth','F':'snake','G':'starfish'}
df['column'] = df['column'].map(d, na_action='ignore').fillna(df['column'])
df

Out[60]: 
     column
0       cat
1     rabit
2   octpath
3    spider
4   mammoth
5     snake
6  starfish
7         -
```

Comment: Thank you, wow, I can use `map`, I see. It worked well, thank you.

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa 
どういたしまして

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace):

```
d = {'A':'cat','B':'rabit', 'C':'octpath','D':'spider','E':'mammoth','F':'snake','G':'starfish'}
df['column'] = df['column'].replace(d)
```

Output:

```
    column
0       cat
1     rabit
2   octpath
3    spider
4   mammoth
5     snake
6  starfish
7         -
```

Comment: It's fantastic. I didn't know that replace can receive dic. This is the simplest. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', '-']})
mapper={'A':'cat','B':'rabit','C':'octpath','D':'spider','E':'mammoth'}
df['column']=df.column.apply(lambda x:mapper.get(x))
0        cat
1      rabit
2    octpath
3     spider
4    mammoth
5    None
6    None
7    None
```

in case you want to set default values

```
 df['column']=df.column.apply(lambda x:mapper.get(x) if mapper.get(x) is not None else "pandas")

  df.column
  0        cat
  1      rabit
  2    octpath
  3     spider
  4    mammoth
  5     pandas
  6     pandas
  7     pandas
```

greatings from shibuya

Comment: Thank you. I use lambda when I need. Thank you.